# Downcasting to Protocol constrained by associated type

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, associated-types, typecasting-operator

I have defined a protocol as follows:

```
protocol CustomCell where Self: UICollectionViewCell {

    associatedType Config
    var cellConfiguration: Config!
    func setup(with configuration: Config)

}
```

I then have a custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
class RedCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, CustomCell {

    var cellConfiguration: RedCollectionViewCellConfiguration!

    func setup(with configuration: Config) {
       ...
    }

   ...awakeFromNib and other functions...

}
```

where `RedCollectionViewCellConfiguration` is defined:

```
class RedCollectionViewCellConfiguration: NSCoding {
     ...
}
```

The ultimate goal is to have many different custom UICollectionViewCells that all conform to CustomCell, with each defining their own custom configuration class (since each type of custom collection view cell will need a different configuration since they will contain different types of data).  I am planning on storing the cell configuration in Core Data, then retrieving it in `ViewController.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`.  In `ViewController.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` I am attempting to do this:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
    cell.setup(tile,with: configuration)
}
```

and I'm getting the following error as a result of the downcast:
*Protocol 'CustomCell' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements*

I have seen other answers on Stack Overflow, but none have helped.  Is there an alternative way to approach this problem?  I've considered not including the associatedType & cellConfiguration in the CustomCell, but it would be ideal if all conforming types had a unique configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you need to remove the associated type, since the generic is in your way and you never needed a generic in the first place. You don't need the protocol either. There is nothing to unify.

Think about this: "with each defining their own custom configuration class" That makes no sense to me. How is *that* going to work? What would unify *these* classes? And why would they need unifying?

Personally I don't see why you don't just use different cell subclasses each of which declares its own configuration method, configuration data type, etc., and leave it at that. That's what I do. Remember, a class can just declare its own internal stuff, including data types. So then you can just say exactly what you are trying to say:

```
if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
    cell.setup(tile,with: configuration)
}
```

because both `setup` and whatever the type of `configuration` is are just things defined inside CustomCell. No associated type, no protocols, no generics, no nothing.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    struct Config { // ...
    func setup(with config: Config) // ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The primary reason for the custom configuration class is that each cell will not only be very different from one another, but we want them each to have lots of variation/customization.  There's no way for us to persist each of these options since the other cells don't have the same options, hence the need for an object that holds the options, which is the unique configuration of each cell.

Comment: Fine, and I just said how to do that. Use different cell class for each cell, each with its own config method and its own type of data. There is nothing to unify here, you don't need generics or protocols. OK now I'm just repeating myself.